How did Chainmail to hit resolution work for OD&D?
I recently bought the hefty "The Making of Original Dungeons & Dragons", weighing in at 576 pages. It is a fascinating resource, with facsimile copies of the original Chainmail Fantasy Supplement, and also Gygax' original, typewritten D&D rules (complete with pencil and ballpen annotations by him and Arneson), and I am trying to understand how combat using these rules originally worked.
However, reading through these primiordial rules sets, a lot of the D&D rules refer to attack resolution for Chainmail with the class tables stating fighting capbabilities in refrence to things such as Man (for a first level Magic-User or cleric), Man(+1) for a first level Fighter, 2 Men(+2), for a second level fighter, Hero for a 4th level fighter, or Super Hero -1 for a 7th level fighter and statements like Clerics: Fight as men until they attain 6th level.
The rules in the Chainmail Fantasy Supplement explain that a HEROES fight like four figures, depending on their arms and equipment classed as ranging from Light Foot to Heavy Horse, and SUPER HEROES are "twice as powerful", which would suggest they fight like 8 units.
But what does the (+1) or -1 or +1 mean? Is there a difference between (+1) and +1? And what does +1 do, is this added to the die roll result of a d6?
I think all of these rules refer to the main CHAINMAIL combat resolution mechanism, and chainmail is also listed as required in the Equpipment list on p. 2. of the manuscript.
As far as I can tell, the facsimile of the Chainmail Fantasy Supplment that is included, is just that -- a supplement -- and does not further explain how the fundamental mechanism for combat resolution for Men in chainmail works. It does list point buy values for Light Foot and an Appendix A of COMBAT TABELES that says things like

LIGHT FOOT vs 
Light Foot   -1 die per man, 6 kills
Heavy Foot   -1 die per 2 men, 6 kills

but it still is rather cryptic to me. Is a man here the same Man as in the OD&D manuscript? Do you roll a d6 for each side if two light foot fight each other, and on a 6 the opponent dies? Do you only roll a d6 for every two units of Light Foot when they fight a unit of Heavy Foot (ignroing a lone leftover Light Foot unit), and if you roll a 6, the Heavy Foot dies?
In the matching HEAVY FOOT table it says

Light Foot   -1 die per man, 5, 6, kills

Does a roll of 5 or 6 kill both Light Foot, or only one unit (I guess the latter)? Is this "minus one" die or is the hyphen just a separator (I think it is)?
Even more puzzling, for HEROES the rules (p. 27 of the manuscript) say

When meleed by regular troops, and combat takes place on the non-Fantasy Combat Tables, four simultaneous kills must be scored against Heroes (or Anti-Heroes) to eliminate them. Otherwise, there is no effect on them.

Orcs for example are not listed in the Appendix E FANTASY COMBAT TABLE (p. 44 TMoODD), which only includes things like Balrogs, Dragons, Giants, Wraithes and other heavy hitters), and they are listed in the Appendix D FANTASY REFERENCE TABLE to attack and defend as "Hv. Ft." which I take to mean Heavy Foot; Goblins and Kobolds attack as "Hv. Ft." and defend as "Lt. Ft." i.e Light Foot.
Does this mean, that an unmounted, lightly armed and armored 4th level Fighter that fights as a HERO using the Light Foot class needs to be hit by four Orcs or Goblins in one round to be immediately killed, but just 2 or 3 Orcs have no way to kill him?
Any insight by some old-school players that have access to and used the full original CHAINMAIL rules welcome.

You can get the chainmail 3rd edition with relative ease.  I had an e copy a while back but it's unfortunately in a folder that got corrupted and I lost a lot of stuff.

@KorvinStarmast The draft recommends using the latest version, but mentions it is by Guidon Games, so I think that was the 2nd Editon at that point (I believe 3rd was put out by TSR themselves), in case that makes any difference in those rules.

Clerics fight as men until they attain 6th level, at which point they fight as boys.

Yes, in the original Dungeons & Dragons rules referencing Chainmail, a 4th level Fighter (a HERO) needs to be hit by four Orcs or Goblins in one round to be killed. This is because:
HERO Status: A HERO fights as four figures, meaning he has the combat strength equivalent to four regular men.
Simultaneous Kills: Chainmail rules state that to kill a HERO, regular troops must score four simultaneous hits in one round.
Combat Mechanics: Orcs and Goblins, when attacking, are treated as Heavy Foot. They each roll one die per attack.
Defense: If fewer than four hits are rolled against the HERO in a single round, he takes no damage.
Therefore, if only 2 or 3 Orcs attack, they cannot meet the requirement of four simultaneous hits needed to kill the HERO in that round.

For person on person combat, they each roll a 2d6, since 2d6 was the combat resolution method in that combat tables in Chainmail.  AFB at the moment or I'd give you more detail.

@KorvinStarmast Aha - so not only was Chainmail an external ruleset, it also had two different ways to resolve combat, depending on if it was field combat or Man vs Man? There is indeed such a table in the facsimile, which seems to entirely ignore the light/heavy foot stuff, and is based on weapon of the attacker and armor of the defender. Then the question is if the 4-hits for a hero rule also applies in man-vs-man combat, which very likely would be the one you use in dungeon encounters.

@NobodytheHobgoblin I will try to summarize this maybe in an answer. It makes no sense to ask this if you don't have access to the 3d or 2d edition rules, honestly.
